# changing select's parent li elements class

Tags: jquery

I have selects in list items. onchange of select, if selected options value is empty, I would like to give the parent li element a "isnotselected" class, else if selected option's value is not empty, I would like to give the parent li element a "isselected" class. How can I do this via jQuery?

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <select>
      <option value="">Select Value</option>
      <option value="1">Value 1</option>
      <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    </select>
  </li>
  <li>
    <select>
      <option value="">Select Value</option>
      <option value="1">Value 1</option>
      <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    </select>
  </li>
  <li>
    <select>
      <option value="">Select Value</option>
      <option value="1">Value 1</option>
      <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    </select>
  </li>
  <li>
    <select>
      <option value="">Select Value</option>
      <option value="1">Value 1</option>
      <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    </select>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **Don't Repeat Yourself** solution:

```
var classes = {
    'true': 'isselected',
    'false': 'isnotselected'
};

$('select').change(function () {
     var sel = !!$(this).val(); // convert value into true/false
     $(this).closest('li').addClass(classes[sel]).removeClass(classes[!sel]);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/B5Q7m/

---

**Alternatively but in the same style**, you can rely on the fact that `false` converts to 0 and 'true' converts to 1, although the `classes` declaration isn't as descriptive:

```
var classes = ['isnotselected', 'isselected'];

$('select').change(function () {
    var sel = !!$(this).val();
    $(this).closest('li').addClass(classes[+sel]).removeClass(classes[+(!sel)]);
});
```

---

**Note**: `.parent()` can be used in place of `.closest('li')`, but `.closest` is usually the safer option in case you decide to wrap the `<select>`s in another element later on.

Comment: Thanks!, appreciate it. Nice Demo!

Answer (score 3):

Very simple:

```
var classes = ['isnotselected', 'isselected'];
$('ul li select').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('li')
           .removeClass(classes.join(' '))
           .addClass(classes[Number(this.value.length > 0)]);
});
```

Comment: +1, though just `this.value` will do for getting the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you also want to remove the opposite class if it is present.  You need to check the `.val()` of the event target on the change event like so:

```
$('select').bind('change',function(e){
    $et = $(e.target);
    if ($et.val() === "") {
        $et.parent().removeClass('isselected')
                    .addClass('isnotselected');
    } else {
        $et.parent().removeClass('isnotselected')
                    .addClass('isselected');
    }        
});
```

I have [created a demo here (link).](http://jsfiddle.net/N9GqZ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/euf3E/1/)

```
$("select").change(function(){
    var $li = $(this).parents("li");
    $li.removeClass("isselected").removeClass("isnotselected");
    if($(this).val())
    {
        $li.addClass("isselected");
    }
    else
    {
        $li.addClass("isnotselected");
    }
});
```

All you need to do is register the change event to the select element to add remove the class isselected and isnotselected.

Comment: As the empty string in JS is a non-truthy value, it's noise to do a boolean comparison. Instead: `if ($(this).val()){ ... }` or more simply `$li.addClass( $(this).val() ? 'isselected' : 'isnotselected' );`

Comment: Thanks, even I didn't get a vote I learned something new tonight.  Thanks again for the tip!