# How i can change a class of a parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

after a form check, I want to add an error class to the form group.

How i can access and do that if i start by having the `"myfieldname"` `$('input[name="myfieldname"]')`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
          <label for="subfolder">text</label>
          <div class="input-group">
             <div class="input-group-addon">test</div>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myfieldid" name="myfieldname">                                                    
           </div>
     </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: And can you please share the JS code you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change parent element style with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34463240/change-parent-element-style-with-jquery) and [Change parent's class with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806719) and [changing select's parent li elements class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772045)

Answer (score 1):

Since you’re using jQuery, it’s quite easy:

```
if (error) {
    $(“input[name=‘myfieldname’]”).parent().parent().addClass(“error”);
}
```

Though you could do it in pure JavaScript like so:

```
if (error) {
    document.querySelector(“input[name=‘myfieldname’]”).parentNode.parentNode.classList.add(“error”);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use [jQuery closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/#closest1)**

> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that
>   matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up
>   through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

```
$('input[name="myfieldname"]').closest('.form-group').addClass('error');
```

Answer (score 0):

now it works

```
var $field.=$('input[name="myfieldname"];
$field.parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-error has-success has-danger has-warning').addClass('new class');
```